# sql select where like option without modulo

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select username from users
where username like ='a%';
```

it is possible to not give any letter after like = ?
I have php input that will find a record in sql, let's say I have no idea what is in sql, and I will try to find "John" by typing only 'Jo', and sql will find all name where no matter 'Jo' is at the beginning, middle or at the end.
To type : where username like ='%';...

Comment: `like =` is not an SQL operator, it should be either `=` or `LIKE`,not both. Perhaps you want `LIKE '%Jo%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the wildcard to either side of the search:

```
select username from users
where username like '%a%';
```

Or from your example:

```
select username from users
where username like '%Jo%';
```

Comment: That works, but instead of "Jo", I place variable '$var'

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help :-)